# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\ge 1}{n^{\log(n)}}x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n\geq 1}{n^{\log(n)}}x^n$.

Is my following try correct and is there any other simpler way to do this:

Let $a_n(x)=n^{\log(n)}x^n$.

If $x\ne0$ then $a_n(x)\not =0$ hence we can apply the ratio test for $x\not = 0$.

So if $x\ne 0$, and since $n^{\log(n)}=e^{\log(n)^2}$ we have that
$$\begin{aligned}\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}(x)}{a_n(x)}\right|&=e^{\log(n+1)^2-\log(n)^2}|x|\\
&=e^{(\log(n+1)-\log(n))*(\log(n+1)+\log(n))}|x|\\
&=e^{\log \left(\dfrac{n+1}{n} \right)\log(n(n+1))}|x|\end{aligned}$$

Now since $\log(\frac{n+1}{n})\sim_\infty \dfrac{1}{n}$ then 
$$\log(\dfrac{n+1}{n})\log(n(n+1))\sim_\infty \dfrac{1}{n}\log(n(n+1))$$ 
But $$\dfrac{1}{n}\log(n(n+1))$$ tends to $0$ by L'Hopitals rule, then
$$\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}(x)}{a_n(x)}\right|$$ tends to $|x|$ hence the radius of convergence is $R=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Or by [Cauchy-Hadamard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) (much simpler, imo):

$$\sqrt[n]{n^{\log n}}=e^{\frac1n\log^2n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^0=1$$

Comment: Reminds me of an observation I have made which is I think correct. Over the last few years there has been a trend to name results after people, even when a perfectly good traditional name (Root Test) was available.

Comment: I don't know what "last few years" means for you, @AndréNicolas. I studied and learned this formula with this name in Calculus II (out of two: year-long courses) back in 1986...